# Не могу получить данные из DB для заполнения AlertDialog

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Доброго времени суток.
Есть listView, который отлично работает и заполняется из БД при помощи CursorLoader'а.

По клику на item из listview вызывается AlertDialog, который должен заполнятся данными исходя из выбранного пункта в listview. 
Но вместо этого ошибка 
**"exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"**, 
но приложение не выключается, а крешится только текущая активити, выкидывая на активити в бекстеке.

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

Вот код обработчика списка (разные варианты пробовал)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String mResource = view.toString();
    String[] dataForLook = db.getCursorByResource(mResource);
    mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_dialog_item,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dataDialogId));
    TextView mLogin = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLoginInfo);
    TextView mPass = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPassInfo);
    TextView mLoginInfo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLoginLook);
    TextView mPassInfo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPassLook);
    mLoginInfo.setText(dataForLook[0]);
    mPassInfo.setText(dataForLook[1]);
    ImageView mSettings = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivSettins);
    ImageView mErase = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivErase);
    ImageView mCancel = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivCancel);
    mSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    mErase.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Вот метод из класса DB

`public String[] getCursorByResource(String resName){
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME,
                COLUMN_LOGIN, COLUMN_PASSWORD},
                COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME + "=?",
                new String[]{resName},null,null,null);
        String login = cursor.getString(2);
        String pass = cursor.getString(3);
        String[] data = new String[]{login,pass};
        cursor.close();
        return data;
    }`

Пытался (в onItemClick) вытащить данные из БД через id, но тоже самое.

`Cursor cursor = db.getById(id);
        String loginInfo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_LOGIN));
        String passInfo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_PASSWORD));
        ...
        mLoginInfo.setText(loginInfo);
        mPassInfo.setText(passInfo);`

Код R.layout.data_dialog_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dataDialogId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoginInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Имя пользователя"
            android:textSize="25sp"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoginLook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Пароль"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassLook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSettins"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivErase"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_erase"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если закомментить

```
//String[] dataForLook = db.getCursorByResource(mResource); 
//        mLoginInfo.setText(dataForLook[0]);
//        mPassInfo.setText(dataForLook[1]);
```

То AlertDialog  создаётся нормально. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно поля в нём заполнить из БД и здесь возникает ошибка.

P.S. Кстати, а id в listview идентичны id в БД, если listview заполняется из этой БД?

Буду весьма благодарен за любую помощь! Спасибо!

Код всей активности, из которой вызывается проблемный АлертДиалог

```
public class DataActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;
    View mView;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    TextView tvDataClear;
    ListView lvData;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    DB db;
    final String LOG_TAG = "my_logs";
    int LOADER_ID = 0;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);

        // открываем подключение к БД
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        String[] from = new String[]{DB.COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvItemText};

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDataList);
        tvDataClear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDataClear);
        if (db.getAllData().getCount() >= 0) {

            tvDataClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lvData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tvDataClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lvData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        lvData.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (db.getAllData().getCount() >= 0) {
            tvDataClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lvData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tvDataClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lvData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    //создаём кнопку добавления данных в БД
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    //вызываем диалог для внесения данных в БД
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemAdd:
                buildAlertDialogAddData();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    //создаём диалог для ввода данных
    public void buildAlertDialogAddData() {
        mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_data, null);
        final EditText mNameRes = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etResName);
        final EditText mLogin = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
        final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etRassword);
        ImageView mYes = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivYES);
        ImageView mNo = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivNO);
        mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mNameRes.getText().toString().isEmpty() || mLogin.getText().toString().isEmpty() || mPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(DataActivity.this,
                            R.string.empty_data,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    db.addRec(mNameRes.getText().toString(), mLogin.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data added to DB");
                    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Loader updated");
                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NO button pressed");
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String mResource = view.toString();
//        String[] dataForLook = db.getCursorByResource(mResource);
//        Cursor cursor = db.getById(id);
//        String loginInfo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_LOGIN));
//        String passInfo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_PASSWORD));
        mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_dialog_item, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dataDialogId));
        TextView mLogin = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLoginInfo);
        TextView mPass = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPassInfo);
        TextView mLoginInfo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLoginLook);
        TextView mPassInfo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPassLook);

//        mLoginInfo.setText(dataForLook[0]);
//        mPassInfo.setText(dataForLook[1]);
        ImageView mSettings = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivSettins);
        ImageView mErase = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivErase);
        ImageView mCancel = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ivCancel);
        mSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
        mErase.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс DB

```
public class DB {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "InfoDB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Resources";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME = "resources";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOGIN = "login";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String DB_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID +
            " INTEGER primary key autoincrement," + COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME +
            " TEXT," + COLUMN_LOGIN + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PASSWORD +
            " TEXT);";

    private final Context mCtx;
    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    final String LOG_TAG = "my_logs";

    public DB(Context ctx) {
       mCtx = ctx;
    }

    // открываем подключение к БД
    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB opened and connected");

    }

    // закрываем подключение к БД
    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null)
            mDBHelper.close();
    }

    // получаем все данные из таблицы DBContract.TABLE_NAME
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "cursor whith alldata created");
        return cursor;

    }

    // добавляем запись в DBContract.TABLE_NAME
    public void addRec(String resName, String login, String pass) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME, resName);
        cv.put(COLUMN_LOGIN, login);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, pass);
        mDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data added to db");
    }

    // удаляем запись из DBContract.TABLE_NAME
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data deleted");
    }

    public String[] getCursorByResource(String resName){
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME,
                COLUMN_LOGIN, COLUMN_PASSWORD},
                COLUMN_RESOURCES_NAME + "=?",
                new String[]{resName},null,null,null);
        String login = cursor.getString(2);
        String pass = cursor.getString(3);
        String[] data = new String[]{login,pass};
        cursor.close();
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getById(long id) {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB created");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: R.layout.data_dialog_item скиньте

Comment: ниже скинул data_dialog_item

Comment: нужно вопрос дополнить, а не в ответе располагать. Исправьте пжл

Comment: mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_dialog_item, null); Попробуйте эту строку заменить на 

View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_dialog_item, !!а здесь присвойте id корневому LinearLayout и вставьте сюда!!);

Comment: View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_dialog_item,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.data_dialog_item_id)); Вернее так

Comment: кстати data_dialog_item.xml ваш не имеет корневого LinearLayout . У вас два под друг другом, если вы правильно скопировали

Comment: @TimurVI, поправил код layout'а.

Comment: а вы создавали объект класса где работаете с бд?

Comment: @TimurVI, обновил вопрос. Внизу код всей активности добавил. Объект db создаётся сразу, и открывается база данных.